# TFS users are displaying at Windows 7 startup

Tags: windows-7

I installed TFS on Windows 7 and added TFS users as Windows users.

Everything works fine.

However, now every time Windows 7 starts, I can see all those TFS users on my startup screen, and I need to select my own user icon to enter my desktop.

Can I do something so that those TFS users would not be displayed at Windows startup?

Comment: @Dave he added a bunch of new users to his windows box.  Those users then show up on the login screen.  That isn't a TFS issue, its a using-a-desktop-as-a-server-without-a-domain-controller issue.  You'd have the same thing happen if you did it with Subversion.  That is, if Subversion can be configured to use windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide these service users by adding them to the SpecialAccounts list in the Registry.

Add the user as a new DWORD value to this key: 
    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`

Set the name of the value to the username and set the value to 0 (zero) to hide it.

More info here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/02/21/how-to-create-hidden-user-account-hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows/

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy! We will try that out.